# Android Volley onResponse not getting Called in Certain Activity

Tags: android, callback, android-volley

I am making Volley GET Requests which will work until I get to a specific activity and then it stops calling the `onResponse` in the `Response.Listener`. Here is my Volley Request method:

```
    public static void stringReqGet(String url, final VolleyCallback callback){
    StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, new Response.Listener<String>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(String response) {
            System.out.println("In VolleyRequest onResponse(): " + response);
            callback.onSuccess(response);
        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            Log.d("Error" ,error.getMessage());
        }

    });
    System.out.println("Adding request to queue: " + stringRequest.toString());
    Utilities.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(stringRequest);
    }
```

Here's how I'm making the request in the activity in question:

```
CourseUtil.loadCourse(courseID, new VolleyCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(String response) {
            System.out.println("JSON Success");
            courseJSON = response;
        }
});
```

and in `CourseUtil` class:

```
public static void loadCourse(int courseID, VolleyCallback callback){
    VolleyRequest.stringReqGet(Const.URL_COURSE + courseID,callback);
}
```

I'm getting no Volley errors just seemingly no response. Here are my (truncated) logs:

```
I/System.out: Adding request to queue: [ ] http://server/courses/267267267 0xebb503b0 NORMAL null
I/System.out: In VolleyRequest onResponse(): *Correct Response Object*
.
.
.
I/System.out: 267267267  <-- Same course ID used in first request
I/System.out: Adding request to queue: [ ] http://server/courses/267267267 0xebb503b0 NORMAL null
*onResponse never called*
```

The first time this request is made you can see that the `onResponse()` method is called and it returns the correct object. The signature of this 'correct' request is the exact same as the one above. The next time that exact request is made the `onResponse` is never called and I get no error.

I've looked at other posts on here but none of their solutions fixed the problem I am having and no error makes it hard to know what's going on.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Do you cancel callback anywhere?

Comment: No, I do not cancel it

Comment: Did you make a single request queue?

Comment: Yes it is a single queue. Got it figured out though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put:

```
System.out.println("JSON Success");
courseJSON = response;
```

into a separate method outside the callback and it works now. Not sure why...